# Django GenericView Update -- sending email if form is saved -- how to?

Tags: django, django-views

I have this UpdateView subclass

```
class UpdateShipView(UpdateView):
    form_class = CruiseShipForm
    template_name = 'cruise/ship_form.html'
    success_url = 'cruise/ships'

    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        obj = CruiseShip.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['ship_id'])
        return obj
```

I want to send an email to certain people with this code:

```
def form_valid():
    msg = 'bla bla'    
    send_mail('Cruise Ship change: ', msg, 'offer_entry@ensembletravel.com',
        user_emails, fail_silently=False)
    return super(UpdateShipView, self).form_valid()
```

I get this error:

```
Django Version: 1.3.1
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:    form_valid() takes no arguments (2 given)
```

I believe I need to re-write form_valid() method but at this point I haven't seen an example to guide me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wanted to follow up with what I finally got to work.

```
import django.contrib.auth as auth
from django.core.mail import send_mail

def form_valid(self, form):
    group = auth.models.Group.objects.get(name='cruise')
    users = group.user_set.all()
    user_emails = []
    for u in users:
        user_emails.append(u.email)
        print u.username, u.email
    cruise_ship = self.get_object()
    msg = "%s (%d) has changed."% (cruise_ship.name, cruise_ship.shipid)
    msg += "\nYou can review it here: http://localhost:8000/cruise/ships/%d/" % cruise_ship.shipid
    # print user_emails  #for debug
    send_mail('Cruise Ship change: ' + cruise_ship.name, msg, 'offer_entry@ensembletravel.com',
        user_emails, fail_silently=False)
        #context = super(PublisherDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

    return super(UpdateShipView, self).form_valid(form)
```

Answer (score 0):

form_valid method of UpdateView object must have arguments "form". Definition of this method must be:

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    ....
```

Comment: Thanks for that @kosmos343 , I changed my form_valid def but how do I properly call the parent form_valid?  and Is this code only being run if the form actually validates? or is form_valid() checking to see if it is

Comment: form_valid called when form is valid, when form isn't valid then called form_invalid method. you can not call parent form_valid, more information you can put from source django/views/generic/edit.py